# IDLE on Mac keeps crashing when using specific keys

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

is anybody experiencing the same issue?
I regularly rush in and start typing shortcuts on my Mac. And sometimes when trying to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (previous) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> (next) to re-run commands, I accidentally the (in spanish ISO keyboard) <kbd>`</kbd> key. This results in IDLE crashing instantly.

I've also found that using mexican <kbd>´</kbd> accent key creates the same crash.

Any idea on how to prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like it might be due to known bugs with the tcl/TK libraries supplied by OS X. See [this very similar IDLE bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue21053). Basically, you should try to install a newer (bug free) version of tcl/TK yourself.

Comment: Well, it was difficult to achieve it but this did it. The only thing is that you should download the 8.5.15 instead of the 8.6. I first installed the 8.6 thinking it was better to use the latest but it didn't work until I used the 8.5.15.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Blckknght I found the answer.

You should install the TCL Version 8.5.15

At first I tried with 8.6 because it was the first "COME AND CLICK ME" button on the [website](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads), but then I learned that the correct version is the one below marked as [8.5.15.0](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads/thank-you?dl=http://downloads.activestate.com/ActiveTcl/releases/8.5.15.0/ActiveTcl8.5.15.1.297588-macosx10.5-i386-x86_64-threaded.dmg)